# how to get innertext from xmlnode C#

Tags: c#, xml, xmlnode, innertext

after I deserialized the xml, i'm able to parse all the elements and attributes. One of the attributes return an XmlNode. When expand the node, I could see the inner text, but not sure how to extract it. Any suggestion?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it figure out..
var xn = (XmlNode[])attribute.DateValue;
var sdate = xn[0].InnerText;

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have a code example

```
XmlNode xnode;
string name  = xnode.InnerText;
```

or on you example

```
string date = attribute.DateValue[0].InnerText;
```

Comment: I couldn't do that since it's seeing as an object

Comment: I would suggest posting your code. the code I have provided has worked for me for a lot of projects so I'm not sure how you implement your code.

Answer (score 0):

You want to get everything from it? I mean everything, that is under the "[0]" in debugger?
Usually You just have to get the value from InnerText - same as if You want to put something into the node, You assign it to InnerText field.